# Is there a function to calculate the sum of numpy ndarray elements returning a 1d array result?

Tags: python, numpy

simple example:

```
a = array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]])

result = []

for i in a:
    result.append(i.sum())

result = [6, 3]
```

Is there a numpy function doing this faster? If it helps: a contains only diagonal matrices.

Edit: 
I just realized that a contains scipy csc_sparse matrices, i.e. its a numpy 1D array containing matrices and i can not apply the sum function with axis=(1, 2)

Comment: `i.sum()` is already a numpy function, since `i` is a numpy array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper use of the `axis` parameter of [`np.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) would do:

```
import numpy as np


np.sum(a, axis=(1, 2))
# [6, 3]
```

---

While the above should be generic preferred method, if your input is actually diagonal over axis 1 and 2, then summing all the zeros is bound to be inefficient (read `O(n² k)` with same `n` and `k` as the `gen_a()` function below). Using `np.sum()` after `np.diag()` inside a loop can be much better (read `O(n k)` with same `n` and `k` as before). Possibly, using a `list` comprehension is the way to go:

```
import numpy as np


np.array([np.sum(np.diag(x)) for x in a])
# [3, 6]
```

---

To give some idea of the relative speed, let's write a function to generate inputs of arbitrary size:

```
def gen_a(n, k):
    return np.array([
        np.diag(np.ones(n, dtype=int))
        if i % 2 else
        np.diag(np.arange(1, n + 1, dtype=int))
        for i in range(k)])


print(gen_a(3, 2))
# [[[1 0 0]
#   [0 2 0]
#   [0 0 3]]

#  [[1 0 0]
#   [0 1 0]
#   [0 0 1]]]
```

Now, we can time for different input size. I have also included a `list` comprehension without the `np.diag()` call, which is fundamentally a slightly more concise version of your approach.

```
a = gen_a(3, 2)
%timeit np.array([np.sum(np.diag(x)) for x in a])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 16 µs per loop
%timeit np.sum(a, axis=(1, 2))
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.51 µs per loop
%timeit np.array([np.sum(x) for x in a])
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop

a = gen_a(3000, 2)
%timeit np.array([np.sum(np.diag(x)) for x in a])
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 20.5 µs per loop
%timeit np.sum(a, axis=(1, 2))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
%timeit np.array([np.sum(x) for x in a])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop

a = gen_a(3, 2000)
%timeit np.array([np.sum(np.diag(x)) for x in a])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop
%timeit np.sum(a, axis=(1, 2))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 34 µs per loop
%timeit np.array([np.sum(x) for x in a])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.93 ms per loop

a = gen_a(300, 200)
%timeit np.array([np.sum(np.diag(x)) for x in a])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
%timeit np.sum(a, axis=(1, 2))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
%timeit np.array([np.sum(x) for x in a])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop
```

And we observe that depending on the value of `n` and `k` one or the other solution gets faster.
For larger `n`, the list comprehension gets faster, but only if `np.diag()` is used.
On the contrary, for smaller `n` and larger `k`, `np.sum()` raw speed can outperform the explicit looping.